# Sorting key value pair on basis of another array

Tags: javascript

I have key value pairs like :

```
var x={1:Car,
2: Cycle,
3:John
}
```

This is response coming from JSON.[Object object]
I have array like :var arr=[1,3,2]
I want to sort x as per arr .
order should be : {1:Car,3:John,2:Cycle}

In javascript how to achieve this.

Comment: Javascript does not guarantee the order of the keys in an object. So, you can't sort them. You can only sort _arrays_.

Comment: can you explain order logic. ascending or descending

Comment: @Arnauld is correct, but if you use `console.log(x)` you will get the properties in alphabetical order. Why do you want to sort the keys of an object any way? There is no point to, even if you could.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort them, just make a new empty array and populate it by getting the values of `arr` and using them as the index of `x`.

```
var x = {
  1: 'Car',
  2: 'Cycle',
  3: 'John'
};
var arr = [1, 3, 2];

var output = [];
arr.forEach(function(item){
    output.push(x[item]);
});
console.log(output);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x1asnv9/).

Answer (score -1):

```
    var order = function(obj, arr) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = obj[arr[i]];
    }
    return temp;
}
var x = {
    1: "Car",
    2: "Cycle",
    3: "John"
}
var arr = [1, 3, 2]
x = order(x, arr);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!